# Main thread and QThread blocking each other

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, pyqt5, qthread

I have been searching on stackoverflow for quite some time today and I am not finding the answer to my problem.  I've tried many suggestions on here with no success yet.

My issue is that I am creating a socket that will run on a separate thread and send back any data received while the main thread is performing other tasks.  Below is the bare minimum main() I am trying to run.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from threadSockRecon import threadSocket
import time

def show_response(data):
    print(str(data))

def main():

    # This section runs the myreceive function loop and receives fine
    # (does not send back to main and main does not loop)
    mySock = threadSocket()
    mySock.connect('127.0.0.1', 8011)
    sockThread = QtCore.QThread()
    mySock.signalStart.emit()
    mySock.moveToThread(sockThread)
    sockThread.start()
    mySock.signalRcvd.connect(show_response)



    # Below will run main thread but not the recieve thread
    # (can send without problems)
    '''
    mySock = threadSocket()
    mySock.connect('127.0.0.1', 8011)
    sockThread = QtCore.QThread()
    mySock.moveToThread(sockThread)
    sockThread.start()
    mySock.signalRcvd.connect(show_response)
    mySock.signalStart.emit()
    '''

    while True:
        print("Spinning ...")
        sMessage = ' getstatus '
        mySock.signalSend.emit(sMessage)
        time.sleep(2)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

As you can see, this calls my socket class called "threadSocket".  Below is this class.

```
# threaded socket
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys, socket
import time

BUFFER_SIZE = 2048

class threadSocket(QtCore.QObject):
    signalStart = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    signalSend = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str) 
    signalRcvd = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.signalStart.connect(self.myreceive)
        self.signalSend.connect(self.mysend)


    def connect(self, host, port):
        try:
            self.sock.connect((host, port))
            print("connected")
        except socket.error as e:
            print("\nConnecting error occurred: " + str(e)  + "\n")
        else:
            pass

    def mysend(self, msg):
        totalsent = 0
        try:
            while totalsent < len(msg):
                sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:].encode('UTF-8'))
                if sent == 0:
                    raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
                totalsent = totalsent + sent
        except socket.error as e:
            print("\nMysend error occurred: " + str(e)  + "\n")
        else:
            pass

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def myreceive(self):
        print("Receiving...")
        chunks = []
        while True:
            try:
                chunk = self.sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                print("chunk: " + str(chunk))
                if chunk == b'':
                    raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
                chunks.append(chunk)
                if ((len(chunks) >= BUFFER_SIZE) or (len(chunks) > 0)):
                    self.signalRcvd.emit(str(b''.join(chunks)))
                    chunks = []
                time.sleep(0.5)
            except RuntimeError as e:
                # put code in here to attempt reconnect
                print("ERROR: Connection Lost: " + str(e) + "\n")
                self.signalRcvd.emit("ERROR")
            except socket.error as e:
                print("\nMyreceive encountered an error: " + str(e) + "\n")
                self.signalRcvd.emit("ERROR")
            else:
                pass

    def close(self):
        print("socket closing")
        self.sock.close()
```

As you can see in my comments in the main(), I can't get them to both run at the same time.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thank you, in advance, for your help. (using Python 3.5.2 and pyqt5)